# angularJS) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.addUpdateList = function (item){
     $scope.targetlist.push(item);
}

$scope.updateTarget = function(){
     $http.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products/productsUpdate',
                {targetList: $scope.targetList});
}
```

body

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in selectResult track by $index | orderBy : 'itemID'">
<td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.siteCode" disabled></td>
<td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemID" disabled></td>
<td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemName"></td>
<td><input ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" type="text" ng-model="item.itemAmt"></td>
<td><select ng-change="addUpdateList(item)" ng-model="item.kitchenPRT_Y">
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select>
</td>
```

chrome error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at m.$scope.addUpdateList

spring error

14:48:52.812 [tomcat-http--43] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void sipos.gim.pos.main.controller.ProductsinfomationController.productsUpdate(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.security.Principal,java.util.List,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]
14:48:52.812 [tomcat-http--43] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void sipos.gim.pos.main.controller.ProductsinfomationController.productsUpdate(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.security.Principal,java.util.List,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]
14:48:52.812 [tomcat-http--43] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void sipos.gim.pos.main.controller.ProductsinfomationController.productsUpdate(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.security.Principal,java.util.List,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c42dd57; line: 1, column: 1]

What's wrong the code?

Comment: `$scope.addUpdateList=function(item){`

Comment: No worries.  Can't comment on your new issue without more code.  Basically the error is teling you that $scope.targetlist is not defined.  You need to initialize it somewhere in your code -- probably with $scope.targetlist = [];

Answer (score 0):

Please correct below code:

```
$scope.addUpdateList(item){
  $scope.targetlist.push(item);
}
```

With:

```
$scope.addUpdateList = function(item){
  $scope.targetlist.push(item);
}
```

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
>
> Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: {1}